# Map Distributing (Backwards) Through a Composition

Tags: functions

I'm reading through ["An Introduction to The Theory of Lists"](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3378/PRG56.pdf) and am having a hard time figuring out how to prove:

$$ (f \circ g)* = (f*) \circ (g*) $$

found on page 5, where the asterisk (*) stands for the map function. I've gone through a basic example of the left hand side, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around composing two already-partially-composed map functions. I know this is pretty basic and I could probably just accept it as fact, but I am curious. Thanks.

Comment: To save others the trouble of looking up the meaning of $*$: If $f$ is a function of type $a\to b$, then $f*$ is the function of type $a\text{ list} \to b\text{ list}$ obtained by applying $f$ elementwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g*$ is the function that applies $g$ to every element of a list.

$f*$ is the function that applies $f$ to every element of a list.

$f\circ g$ is the function that  applies $g$ to something,  then $f$ to the result.

$(f\circ g)*$ is the function that applies $g$, then $f$, to every element of a list.

So the identity says that applying $g$, then $f$ to every element of a list, is the same as applying $g$ to every element of the list and then applying $f$ to every element of the resulting list.

Does that help?

---

Or here's an example.  Suppose $f$ is the function that takes $n$ and gives you $10\cdot n$, and $g$ is the function that takes $n$ and gives you $n+1$.

- Then $f\circ g$ is the function that takes $n$ to $10\cdot(n+1)$.
- $f*$ is the function that applies $f$ to every element of a list; it takes a list like $[1,2,4,7]$ and yields the list $[10,20,40,70]$.
- $g*$ is the function that applies $g$ to every element of a list; it takes a list like $[1,2,4,7]$ and yields the list $[2,3,5,8]$.
- If you take the list $[1,2,4,7]$ and aply $g*$ you get $[2,3,5,8]$, and if you apply $f*$ to that list you get $[20,30,50,80]$.
- That is the same result as if you did $f\circ g$ to each element of $[1,2,4,7]$ one at a time.

Comment: Makes total sense. I just got too stuck on the notation that I couldn't come up with a concrete example. Thanks!